# How to assess stability of daily time series in sentiment analysis?

Tags: time-series, variance, reliability, kolmogorov-smirnov-test, resampling

I developed a measure of "sentiment" and I have time based data and used the measure to derive a daily sentiment time series. I am looking for some way to establish reliability or maybe stability. For example, when there are dramatic changes in the "sentiment" is this "real". Two ideas for doing this numerically start with re-sampling the data. By this I mean, drawing random samples ( on a per day basis so that for example if I have 100 data points per day, I would have 25 data points per day in each of the random samples).

Then, one way of establishing reliability would be testing the average variance in the resulting curves (distributions).

The other way was to take each of the resulting data sets and perform pairwise the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test was  and check the significance values.

Can anyone comment on either of these approaches or suggest another?

Comment: Are you looking for sudden breaks (aka changepoints) in your time series? Do you have any idea on the process that your data follow? Is it random walk, is it stationary, what is the autocorrelation structure? BTW, the tags `reliability` and `resampling` sound a bit misleading, at least in terms of the problem you're **apparently** trying to solve. Just my two cents...